# check publish_action permission using javascript

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

How can I check if the user has given permission and not disabled (publish_action) permission
to do post (publish_action) using open graph apis ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a call to `/me/permissions` with the user's access token or `/USER_ID/permissions` with the app access token. It shows which permissions you have for that user.

Sample output is:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "installed": 1, 
      "manage_pages": 1, 
      "user_actions.music": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: cool : I tried this - 10000153/permissions?access_token='AAACEd' and got {
  "data": [
    {
      "installed": 1, 
      "email": 1, 
      "publish_actions": 1
    }
  ]
}